# Make a Linux "GUI" in the command line

Tags: linux, user-interface, command-line

How to make a Linux program in the Command Line Interface who display a nice user interface?

For example when I use "wget" to download a file from internet, I can see the download advancement in the Command Line Interface.  How can I do that?

Comment: What's the language that you want to write this frontend?

Comment: This [1] seems to be what you're looking for.
[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_user_interface

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)). It is a library for text based UI.

Answer (score 17):

[ncurses](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1124) is a popular option, there are APIs for lots of programming languages.

Answer (score 11):

You can get a basic interface by using `\r` to go to the beginning of the current line.

Slightly more advanced is [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

The next step up is [Newt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_(programming_library)).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to do a GUI for Bash scripts or to wrap around other command line utilities, you can use [dialog](http://hightek.org/dialog/) ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog)).

Here two great dialog tutorial to get you started :

- [Dialog: An Introductory Tutorial](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807)
- [Improve Bash Shell Scripts Using Dialog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2460).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call wget's progress report as a 'nice gui', but anyway, the classic library for building graphical interfaces without X Windows is Linux and UNIX systems is [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Recently a C# version of ncurses has been started, check out details [here](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a progress bar, this can be done directly with a simple `print` (that prints the bar), followed by the **carriage return character** (ANSI character #13), which puts you back at the beginning of the line.  The line can then be later updated by printing over it.

For more complicated needs, `ncurses` is indeed the standard way to go.

Answer (score 1):

One should mention [FTXUI](https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/FTXUI). Functional Terminal (X) User interface: A simple C++ library for terminal-based user interfaces!

- Cross-Platform
- Support for UTF8 and fullwidth chars (→ 测试)
- No dependencies
- etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mono, you could use [MonoCurses](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoCurses)

Answer (score 0):

Try curses, it is a well documented API for text based UI.Also, there is so much open source projects that are using curses for you see and learn

Answer (score 0):

wget does not really have a GUI, all I see is stuff that you can already achieve using stdout and echos (e.g. printf() or std::cout)

Anyways, for simple dialog boxes of the MessageBox kind, but not limited to that, also have a look at dialog

- http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog
- http://hightek.org/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can just use ANSI escape codes. A simple example in bash

```
echo -e "\033[H\033[2J  \033[20;20H  \033[4mThis is a underlined line.\033[0m"
```